# Modificar valores de un diccionario c#

Tags: c#

Declare un diccionario como estrucutura de datos sin embargo no he encontrado la forma de modificar los valores que le corresponden a la llave (estos valores es un objeto de clase Persona). ¿Como puedo realizar esto?. Gracias.

```
private void modificarRegistroH(Dictionary<long, Persona> tablaRegistros)
        {
            Persona datos = tablaRegistros[convertirAscii(txtPasaporteH.Text)];
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo debes asignar los valores a las propiedade de la entidad Persona

```
private void modificarRegistroH(Dictionary<long, Persona> tablaRegistros)
{
    long key = convertirAscii(txtPasaporteH.Text);
    Persona datos = tablaRegistros[key];

    datos.Prop1 = valor;
    datos.Prop2 = valor2;

}
```

No necesitas volver asignar este en el diccionario porque al ser todo objetos trabajan por referencia, modificando la entidad que recuperas del diccionario automaticamente es actualizada